# Docker: connection between golang webapp and postgres server refused

Tags: postgresql, go, docker, docker-compose

I can't connect my Postgres container with my golang webapp container.

i got following error:

`panic: dial tcp [::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused`

My docker compose file:

http://pastebin.com/5LQfn3gy

Any idea how i can fix that?

Comment: you need to change the ports:  ports:
           - "81:82"

Comment: In your `api` containers environment declaration, try `DSN: "db://postgres:postgres@db:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"`. This will connect directly to the `db` container. `127.0.0.1` is the localhost inside your go container, not your host machines localhost.

Comment: try to replace this one         ports:
           - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432" to 5432:5432

Comment: i have changed 127.0.0.1:5432 to :5432 but now i getting this `panic: dial tcp [::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused`

Comment: @Donutloop This might be the solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366545/516512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the IP you specified relates to your host and not your docker environment and you're running your app inside docker too, just omit the IP:

```
ports:
  -5432:5432
```

So you'd just need to pass the Postgres alias, followed by its port to your go app (either as an env var or a flag).