# Can't connect to Postgres docker container from Golang container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a web server built using golang. It works successfully when I test it locally.

However, when I build a docker image for my web server, it can't connect to a running Postgres container.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
    go:
        image: golang:1.7
        volumes:
          - ./:/server/http
        ports:
            - "80:8080"
        links:
            - postgres
            - mongodb
            - redis
        environment:
            DEBUG: 'true'
            PORT: '8080'

    postgres:
        image: onjin/alpine-postgres:9.5
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
            POSTGRES_DB: mydb
    mongodb:
        image: mvertes/alpine-mongo:3.2.3
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"

    redis:
        image: sickp/alpine-redis:3.2.2
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.7

RUN mkdir -p /home/app

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY . /home/app

RUN make deps && make

ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/api-test"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

The Postgres connection string I am using:

```
postgresql://user:pass@host/mydb?sslmode=disable
```

For host, I tried `localhost` and it returns the following error:

```
dial tcp [::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Tried `postgres` and it returns the following:

```
dial tcp 202.71.99.194:5432: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Tried the IP address I get running this command which returns `172.19.0.3`:

```
docker inspect apitest_postgres_1 | grep IPAddress
```

where `apitest_postgres_1` is Postgres container name. It also returned this error:

```
dial tcp 172.19.0.3:5432: getsockopt: connection timed out
```

Can you please tell me what I am missing here? I am inexperienced with docker and this took a long time investigating for a solution.

**Edit:**
I run my golang docker using this command:

```
docker run --env-file ./example.env --rm -it -p 8080:8080  api-test
```

`example.env` is the file contains my environment vars.

**Edit 2:**
I changed the connection string to the following:

```
postgresql://user:pass@postgres:5432?sslmode=disable
```

It returns the following error:

```
dial tcp: lookup postgres on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host
```

I'm getting the idea that my mac is the issue here. My default DNS is `8.8.8.8` which should not be a problem.

Comment: have you tried set `postgres` as host in url `postgresql://user:secret@postgres/mydb?sslmode=disable` ? Just the same as the service name.

Comment: @Зелёный yup tried it and it returned the following error: `dial tcp 202.71.99.194:5432: getsockopt: connection refused`

Comment: Are you sure you allow All Connections Over TCP/IP Networks in the Postgres `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: @Зелёный this is the solution! But how can I modify `pg_hba.conf` for a downloaded docker container? I could not run `docker exec -it apitest_postgres_1 bash` to change it.

Comment: You able to extend the base image and do what you wanna do. Give me some time I'll post an answer with Dockerfile.

Comment: Looks like that images already has `listen_addresses=*`, which allow all connections. https://github.com/onjin/docker-alpine-postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L41, so the problem is not in `pg_hba.conf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're pulling go image instead of building you're own image.

Instead of `image: golang:1.7` replace it with `build: .` to build and use your `Dockerfile`.

Also you might need to pass postgres environment variables `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASS` etc. you can achieve that but creating for example `docker.env` file and then add `env_file` under your go app `docker-compose.yml` file:

Example docker.env :

```
DB_HOST=postgres
DB_USER=user
DB_PASS=pass
DB_NAME=mydb
```

Corrected docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        volumes:
          - ./:/server/http
        ports:
            - "80:8080"
        links:
            - postgres
            - mongodb
            - redis
        environment:
            DEBUG: 'true'
            PORT: '8080'
        env_file: 
          - docker.env

    postgres:
        image: onjin/alpine-postgres:9.5
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
            POSTGRES_DB: mydb

    mongodb:
        image: mvertes/alpine-mongo:3.2.3
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"

    redis:
        image: sickp/alpine-redis:3.2.2
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a connection to postgres in docker compose becomes established, you need to replace **localhost** or **127.0.0.1** or **postgres** in your connection string with the name of the container being mentioned in your docker compose file.

For example, in your docker-compose.yaml file create database like this:

```
db:
    container_name: composepostgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
```

and then, in your code when creating your connection string, avoid using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` or `postgres`, and instead use `composepostgres` in the place of them.

If not doing so, you will face with `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused` error.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a this documentation : https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Then, regarding the links in you docker-compose file, replace "host" by "postgres" in you connection string :

```
postgresql://user:pass@postgres/mydb?sslmode=disable
```

Let the embedded DNS server do the mapping work because the ip address may change every time you recreate the container.

Also, ensure postgres allows connection (maybe limited to localhost)

Answer (score -1):

you can use docker.for.mac.localhost instead localhost or postgres ...
`postgresql://user:pass@docker.for.mac.localhost/mydb?sslmode=disable`

It worked for me but only for mac.